# Как найти верхнюю точку пресечения двух окружностей?

Tags: svg, геометрия

Необходимо получить координаты верхней точки пересечения 2-x окружностей, для построения треугольника. Идея такова:

Рисуем две прозрачных окружности, получаем точку и потом рисуем сам треугольник. Все три стороны мне известны (они же радиусы).

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: я так понимаю радиусы и координаты центров заданы?

Comment: @StrangerintheQ Да)

Comment: а центры обязательно лежат на прямой параллельной оси x?

Comment: @StrangerintheQ Да, а смысл их располагать иначе для отрисовки?

Comment: вот тут есть решение в общем случае http://paulbourke.net/geometry/circlesphere/

Comment: При чем здесь треугольник? Какой треугольник? И почему точка - "вечерняя"? Она, что, по утрам - другая?

Comment: @Igor Про вечер исправили. Треугольник же вопрошающему надо построить по центрам кругов и точке их пересечения.

Comment: может быть верхней точкой будет та, у которой y(игрик) больше?

Comment: https://codepen.io/strangerintheq/pen/voBwJm

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Фактически задача и сводится к построению треугольника по известным длинам трех его сторон.

Пусть центр левой окружности - это точка `A`, центр правой окружности - это точка `B`, а искомая точка их пересечения - точка `C`. Пусть `a`, `b` и `c` - длины сторон `BC`, `AC` и `AB` соответственно. Эти длины вам даны сразу. `b` - это радиус левой окружности, `a` - радиус правой окружности, а `c` - расстояние между их центрами.

1. Если на минутку мысленно представить, что точки `A` и `B` лежат на оси X и точка `A` попадает в точку `(0, 0)`, а точка `B` - в точку `(c, 0)`, то тогда в такой системе координат кординаты "верхней" вершины `C` будут равны

   ```
   xC = (b^2 + c^2 - a^2) / (2 * c)
   yC = sqrt(b^2 - Cx^2)
   ```
2. Это дает нам способ решения исходной задачи. Сначала решаем задачу 1 и получаем величины `xC` и `yC`. Затем откладываем на отрезке `AB` отрезок `AD` длины `xC`. Это дает нам точку `D`. Затем мысленно строим перпендикуляр к прямой `AB` в точке `D` и по направлению "вверх" откладываем на нем отрезок `DC` длины `yC`. Это даст нам искомую точку `C`.

   При этом величина `xC` может оказаться больше длины отрезка `AB`, т.е. точка `D` может "улететь" за пределы этого отрезка. Ничего страшного и необычного в этом нет.

   [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

Альтернативным вариантом шага 2 будет:

2. Решить задачу 1 и получить точку `(xC, yC)`. Затем *повернуть* эту точку на угол между осью X и прямой `AB`, получив в результате точку `(xC', yC')`. Затем прибавить к ней координаты точки `A`, получив искомую точку `(xA + xC', yA + yC')`.

   Но при этом надо рассмотреть две точки: `(xC, ±yC)`, ибо сразу не ясно, какая из них после поворота станет "верхней".

Comment: А методами `svg` ни как не найти?

Comment: @doox911 можно найти но надо пользоваться редакторами векторной графики ..типа inkscape и т д  там есть много опций для этого